# Ubuntu 16.04.1 installation

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

Each time I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32bit operating system in Oracle VM Virtualbox, something goes wrong with the display of virtualbox.

[image: The display that I get.]

Comment: try disabling 3d accelleration from vbox settings

Comment: No changes. The same display.

Comment: Any answers please.

Comment: maybe bad image? did you try 64bit? Why are you using 32bit?

Comment: Try press ctrl+alt+F1, ctrl+alt+F2, and then ctrl+alt+F1. This is the shortcuts that switches tty console. If you press them, your screen will be fine.